# Battery Indicator Error. D-Bus

Tags: power-management, battery, dbus

So I installed the detailed Battery Indicator that was [shown on OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/), and it worked fine for a few days. Now, every time I login I get this:
[image: Error]

I tried to go back to the old indicator, but it appears to be a D-Bus error. Any ideas?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 (Yes, I use Unity. I've also tried *NOT* using Unity in a hope that it had something to do with that and that the error was misleading, but I got the exact same results) on an Asus EEE PC, and here is what I get when I run `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info` *when it's plugged in*:

```
james@tristan:~$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info
present:                 yes
design capacity:         4400 mAh
last full capacity:      4266 mAh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          10800 mV
design capacity warning: 10 mAh
design capacity low:     5 mAh
cycle count:          0
capacity granularity 1:  44 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  44 mAh
model number:            1005P
serial number:            
battery type:            LION
OEM info:                ASUS
james@tristan:~$
```

I get the exact same output when I'm **not** plugged in as well.

***EDIT: THERE IS NO `BAT1`. I'm now on 11.04 beta, and I'm still getting the same error**

Another edit: Output of  `acpitool -b`

`Battery #1     : discharging, 100.0%`

Comment: By "plugged in" do you mean that the battery is plugged in or that the AC adapter is plugged in? Also, what exactly happened when you tried to go back to the old indicator?

Comment: Battery is always plugged in - although I did take it out for a moment to see if that was the problem. What I meant by "plugged in" was that the AC adapter is plugged in. As for what happened when I tried to go back, nothing. I selected the indicator applet in normal GNOME, and it didn't do anything - no new icon in the menubar, no error. Nothing happened. Most annoying/puzzling.

Comment: Could you please install acpitool and provide the output of `acpitool -B` without the adapter plugged in?  Note: it might be `-b` and not `-B`.  My laptop's in Windows & I can't reboot for a few minutes, but I'm asking for the acpi battery output info (definitely available via `acpitool -e`, but that's a bit verbose for here...)

Comment: @M tibbits Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a know bug that can be solved by this:
Lets make a backup first:

```
 sudo cp /usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status /usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status.bak
```

And then:

```
 sudo sed -i 's/BAT0/BAT1/g' /usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1c510b08c587a8cacb19 - the PPA isn't found.

Comment: I'm sorry I am at my mobile. I will check that when I get home. Until then you could try what I've added to the answer.

Comment: You just solved it for me. I followed your instructions, logged out and it worked.... THANK YOU. :D

Comment: I'm glad to help. ;-)